# ffmpeg-python trim with start&end frame resulting in broken video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

```py
import ffmpeg

stream = ffmpeg.input("input.mp4")
stream = ffmpeg.trim(stream, start_frame=100, end_frame=125)
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, "test.mp4")
ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

I tried to trim the video by given specific frame.

but **sometimes** the resulting video is broken (can open it, but instantly jump to the end, and the video is all black)

I've check the input video, it's not broken.

Comment: You specify the start and end points for the `trim` filter. So, your command is outputting 25-frame video, which indeed lasts for a very short time... Is this what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to trim just the frame part you set, you have to do something like this:

```
(
ffmpeg
.input(input_video, ss='00:05:20', t='00:10:00')
.output('output.mp4')
.run()
)
```

So you get just the cut from the video and the video stream is not continuing. What you did is that you trimmed the part as you wished but the stream continued, so you had a black window after that.